# Snort not working with IDSWakeup

Tags: ids, snort, detection, intrusion

I have setup Snort with the registered user rules installed. 
I tested first by making the following rule in local.rules:

```
alert icmp any any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"ICMP test"; sid:10000001; rev:001;)
```

That rule works fine, and I tested a TCP rule as well which also worked.

The problem I'm having is that I'm expecting snort to produce an output when 
`snort -A console -q -i eno16780032 -u snort -g snort -k none -c /etc/snort/snort.conf` is run

Again, I can see the output from my ICMP rule in local.rules, I just can't see anything when I run  `./IDSwakeup 127.0.0.1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1 1` from another PC. (All rules under part 7 are uncommented, part 8 and 9 are left commented)